# Winsock 400 Bad Request, openresty

Tags: c++, winsock

So I have a authentication system for my software where I send a GET request to my server that validates it which then echos back true or false. When ever I use Winsock to send the HTTP request I get an error: 400 bad request and below it is openresty. Any help appreciated!

```cpp
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400

#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

void main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET Socket;
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    int lineCount = 0;
    int rowCount = 0;
    struct hostent* host;
    locale local;
    char buffer[10000];
    int i = 0;
    int nDataLength;
    string website_HTML;

    // website url
    string url = "www.mysitewebsite.com/auth/auth.php?hwid=" + hwidPro +
                 "&username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password;

    // HTTP GET
    string get_http =
        "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + url + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
        // return 1;
    }

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    host = gethostbyname("www.mysite.com");

    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

    if(connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0) {
        cout << "Could not connect";
        system("pause");
        // return 1;
    }

    // send GET / HTTP
    send(Socket, get_http.c_str(), strlen(get_http.c_str()), 0);

    // recieve html
    while((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while(buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            website_HTML += buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();

    const char* result = website_HTML.c_str();
    Log::Msg(result);
    if(website_HTML == "true") {
        authsucsess();

    } else {
        Log::Fatal(result);
        Log::Fatal("Invalid Login or HWID");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

I have edited my post the be a minimal, reproducible example. Hope its better
Edit 2: I have added the HTTP response:

```html
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 
Date: Sat, 22 Jun 2019 21:33:11 GMT
Content-type: text/html
content-length: 170
connection: close
Server: awex
X-Xss Protection: 1; mode=block 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Request-ID: 7ccdf09347f06d7a061ad41aa45d5af7

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Things like `host = gethostbyname(www.mysite.com");` will not compile and makes it unnecessarily hard to help. You're also missing `include`s and ... `main`. One note, not related to the problem: You are sending the username and password unencrypted. The ~15 hops between sender and receiver can all extract it as cleartext.

Comment: The host = gethostbyname(www.mysite.com"); without the quotations is not in my build, it happened while censoring my site. I also have all the libraries needed for it, I am able to compiled but when using it, I have that error code. ( Log::Fatal(result); is a popup window that shows what came back. And it is the HTML basically saying 400 bad request. openresty. I really don't know where the code is wrong.

Comment: "_not in my build_" - I don't know what that means, but `gethostbyname(www.mysite.com")` is what you put in your question. I don't doubt that you have all the necessary libraries. What you should do is to create a minimal example that anyone else can copy and compile without modification.

Comment: Not in my build meaning that it wasnt like that in the version of the code I compiled. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, put compilable code, condensed into a bare minimum, in the question. SO is supposed to be an archive of Q&A:s so external links to explain questions aren't usually a good idea. The code you shared in the link looks like it could be put in the question as-is. Just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56718759/edit) the question.

Comment: Sorry im really new to this website and can usually fix my problems myself. This one really stumped me. Also I did a paste bin link seeing as I couldnt post it in a comment. From here can you help me?

Comment: @73areo No worries, just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56718759/edit) your question and put the correct code in it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have edited my question accordingly. and πάντα ῥεῖ I censored the link of my website where the data was being sent to

Comment: Ok, I see. It's not related to your question but you have some problems in that code. You are calling `main`. That's not allowed. .. and still, that code can't be compiled (because of `host = gethostbyname(www.mysite.com");`). Copy it yourself and try to compile it, correct the errors, verify that it still has the original issue and then re-edit your question.

Comment: Ok  I have fixed the errors mentioned above and I get the same error (Note: Its not a compiler error, everything compiles fine. I logged the HTTP response and saw that it read back the 400 bad request openresty  toggling the else statement closing the application)

Comment: Great! Now there's a much better chance of someone coming along helping out.

Comment: I just ran the program again and here is the HTTP response:

Comment: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 
Date: Sat, 22 Jun 2019 21:33:11 GMT
Content-type: text/html
content-length: 170
connection: close
Server: awex
X-Xss Protection: 1; mode=block 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Request-ID: 7ccdf09347f06d7a061ad41aa45d5af7

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: That looks like a simple protocol error. Could it be your `Host:` field? it's supposed to contain the host (`www.mysitewebsite.com`), not a `URI` (`www.mysitewebsite.com/auth/auth.php?hwid=...`

Comment: I will try that and come back with results

Comment: @73areo Since you are clearly coding for Windows, why not use the WinInet or WinHTTP API to send HTTP requests, instead of using Winsock directly?

Comment: You'll have to adjust your `GET` too. Either make the `URI` into a full `URL` and use that instead of `/` (which will get you the site top document) or strip away the unnecessary parts covered by the hostname.

Comment: that has crashed my application instantly just to confirm this is what you meant?                   `string get_http = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";`

Comment: The `Host` field should in this case be `Host: www.mysite.com`.

Comment: I believe that is what I did, no? and also I don't quite understand what you with adjusting the GET, like this: Host: http://example.com ? (meant for the http to be there, it got taken away)

Comment: Your `GET /` fetches the top document but you'd like the `auth/auth.php?hwid=...` document. To make it easy, provide the fulll `URL` (`http://www.mysitewebsite.com/auth/auth.php?hwid=) in the `GET` request and I think the webserver will accept it (even without the `Host` field.

Comment: ... what @RemyLebeau just provided :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GET` request is malformed. This is what you are sending:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysitewebsite.com/auth/auth.php?hwid=[...]&username=[...]&password=[...] 
Connection: close
```

It needs to look like this instead:

```
GET /auth/auth.php?hwid=[...]&username=[...]&password=[...] HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysitewebsite.com
Connection: close
```

Try this:

```cpp
string s_host = "www.mysitewebsite.com";
string s_resource = "/auth/auth.php";
string s_query = "?hwid=" + hwidPro + "&username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password;

string url = s_host + s_resource + s_query;

string get_http = "GET " + s_resource + s_query + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: " + s_host + "\r\n"
    "Connection: close\r\n"
    "\r\n";

...

host = gethostbyname(s_host.c_str());

...

send(Socket, get_http.c_str(), get_http.size(), 0);

...

while((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) > 0)
{
    website_HTML.append(buffer, nDataLength);
}

...
```

Comment: previous code did crash my app trying with updated code now

Comment: Thank you so much your a life saver! now how can I remove the stuff from the response, like the http info

Comment: @73areo The best way to thank someone (and to remove the question from the list of unanswered questions) is to accept the answer.

Comment: @73areo you need to parse the response. At the very least, you can use an `std::istringstream` to read lines (the HTTP response headers) from `website_HTML` until a blank line is encountered. Everything after that is the body data you are looking for.